# Solr query which accepts multiple fileds returns the first non-null value in a list like coalesce in oracle

Tags: java, solr, lucene, spring-data-solr

We have requirement where there are three fields user date, recorded date and encoded date. 
   We use Solr for searching and we have requirement to retrieve records using condition if value exists for user date use it else check for recorded date and if it also doesn't contain value use encoded date and if all three fields contains no value ignore that field.

This requirement is similar to COALESCE functionality in oracle where It accepts two or more parameters and returns the first non-null value in a list. If all parameters contain null values, it returns null.

**Update** :: We are using Solr 3.5.0

For example below is my values in table

```
 DocumentID   User entered date      Recorded date      Encoded date
    A123        14th April 2016     12th April 2016 
    A124        12th April 2016                         11th April 2016
    A125                            13th April 2016     12th April 2016
    A126                            12th April 2016 
    A127                                                15th April 2016
```

If we search for April 12th 2016 then Solr should return me output as A124, A126 and not A123 or A125 because we have user entered date and recorded date for those fields respectively.

Comment: I think you need to tackle this at your end once your get the data by applying some logic...

Comment: it can be implemented with a simple query using boolean conditions OR

Comment: @Oyeme I tried OR condition but if there are values for both user date and recorded date. SOLR is searching in both fields which is not i am looking for.

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti I was looking for that such logic.

Comment: @rajadilipkolli you can use DataImportHanlder to write your own sql with all conditions and solr will index it :)

Comment: @Oyeme I have updated question with my clear requirement, we have index running and don't want to do full indexing again and only recently we have introduced user entered date so i think we should be looking beyond **DataImportHandler**

Comment: You can try to use functions someting like {!func}exists(Field,1,0) http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#if

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109820/discussion-between-rajadilipkolli-and-oyeme).

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is probably to copy the fields into a separate field in the order you want and then only keep the first value. In the latest Solr, I believe this can be done in the UpdateRequestProcessor step with [CloneField](http://www.solr-start.com/javadoc/solr-lucene/org/apache/solr/update/processor/CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory.html) and then [FirstFieldValue](http://www.solr-start.com/javadoc/solr-lucene/org/apache/solr/update/processor/FirstFieldValueUpdateProcessorFactory.html) processors. However, I am quite sure, these URPs were introduced in 5.x, and so are not available in Solr 3.5.

I suspect you would really have to apply this domain logic in the data before it is sent to Solr.

Comment: Alex i agree with you but the problem is recorded date and encoded date are existing fields and we have added user date recently. so changing logic is also a problem and if you see table structure, it may contain null values and values can be added anytime

Comment: You mean that you have already records indexed like that and reindexing is not an option? You are looking for pure query-time solution?

Comment: Yeah pure query time solution in SOLR 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with specifying field names to query with. something like this

```
q=foo&qf=title,description
```

Did you try this

First query with only first field, user entered date. fetch all DocumentID. second, query with(same q value) something like if user field value is null and then search in second field value , fetch DocumentsID. Do the same for third field also. finally merge all DocumentsID.

Comment: I tried this but it wont solve the problem mentioned in the question

Comment: ok, query with only first field, user entered date. fetch all DocumentID. second, query with(same q value) something like if user field value is null and then search in second field value , fetch DocumentsID. Do the same for third field also. finally merge all DocumentsID.

Comment: This approach could be a solution but hitting thrice is performance oriented, so can't be done in that way

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're looking for `if(expression,trueValue,falseValue)` function described in [FunctionQuery](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#if)

For example, for dismax query parser you can define boost function like

```
bf="recip(rord(if(exists(u_date),u_date,if(exists(r_date),r_date),if(exists(e_date),e_date,0))),1,1000,1000)"
```

Comment: [FunctionQuery](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#if) is introduced in Solr 4.0 but the version which we are using is Solr 3.5